# How to uninstall tor on kali linux?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I installed tor on my kali linux and it is not working I tried every way to rectify it but it doesn't open at all it shows this
that cannot be rooted and

```
Aug 28 00:06:26.946 [notice] Tor v0.2.4.27 (git-412e3f7dc9c6c01a) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.19-stable and OpenSSL 1.0.1e.
Aug 28 00:06:26.946 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Aug 28 00:06:26.946 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Aug 28 00:06:26.951 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Aug 28 00:06:26.951 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
Aug 28 00:06:26.951 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
Aug 28 00:06:26.951 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings
I hope u will help me 
tAug 28 00:06:26.946 [notice] Tor v0.2.4.27 (git-412e3f7dc9c6c01a) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.19-stable and OpenSSL 1.0.1e.
Aug 28 00:06:26.946 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Aug 28 00:06:26.946 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Aug 28 00:06:26.951 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Aug 28 00:06:26.951 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
Aug 28 00:06:26.951 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
Aug 28 00:06:26.951 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings
```

Comment: Hi there. It's not completely clear what you're asking. Do you want to know how to uninstall Tor, as the title would suggest, or do you want someone to help you get things running smoothly?

Answer (score 1):

The log is explaining what is going wrong:

> Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor
> already running?

You are not telling us exactly how you installed it and try to run it.
Did you install with apt-get? Compile it from source and then run it from a custom directory?

But if you have it installed with 'apt-get' and want to remove it then do this as root:

```
apt-get remove tor
```

It should then remove the installed tor.

I believe that the torbrowser that is needed to be removed.  There is a difference
to do that:

**sudo apt remove -y tor torbrowser-launcher**

should do the job

Cheers